# SignalR returns 'HubName' is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

Im trying SignalR and I'm getting javascript error: Status is undefined. The Status is my hub and it is defined as:

```
namespace SignalRDemo
{
    public class Status : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
    {

        public Task Disconnect()
        {
          return Clients.leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        public Task Connect()
        {
          return Clients.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        public Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
        {
          return Clients.rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

     }
}
```

When I try url http://localhost:16476/signalr/hubs, i have received the javascript code, but there is missing Status hub instance.

I have referenced the following assemblies: SignalR.dll, Newtonsoft.Json.dll, WebActivator.dll, Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll

My default.aspx site looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> 
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/json2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs")      %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var status = $.connection.status;

status.joined = function (id, when) {
  if ($.connection.hub.id === id) {
    addMessage(id, 'blue');
  }

addMessage(id + ' joined at ' + when, 'green');
};

status.rejoined = function (id, when) {
addMessage(id + ' reconnected at ' + when, 'purple');
};

status.leave = function (id, when) {
addMessage(id + ' left at ' + when, 'red');
};

function addMessage(value, color) {
$('#messages').append('<li style="background-color:' + color + ';color:white">' +    value + '</li>');
}

$.connection.hub.start({ transport: activeTransport });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This example is copied from the official SignalR examples. I have created my own asp.net web application and put the code there. Can somebody to navigate
me what I miss please?

Comment: Can you try changing the code to <script type="text/javascript" src='/signalr/hubs'></script>?

Comment: I have tried it, but the same error. As I wrote in my question the url http://localhost:16476/signalr/hubs is reachable, but there is missing instance of the hub. I think, that the problem is on the server side, because it doesn't render the hub instance.

Comment: where is activeTransport defined?  also did you add signalR via nuget or manually?

Comment: Where did you put the Status.cs for the hub? Make sure it is in the App_Code directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@drch: good question. I have forgot to define activeTransport. But it was just a secondary problem.

I have solved my problem thanks to point from aKzenT. I have change my web application project to web site project. Because in the web application, there was not option to add App_Code folder.

Then I had some problems when I run the web site from visual studio on dynamic port. In the debug console it writes, that jquery.js not found, json2.js not found...for all js files. When I deployd it to the iis it began to work.